# Google Analytics: filter page views or sessions with certain actions or labels?

Tags: google-analytics

I was wondering if it's possible that to filter page views or sessions that have certain actions/labels occurring ?

For example, I have tracked a "search" event or label. Is there a way where I can filter page views or sessions where a "search" event has occurred ?

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

One option is to create a custom report, of a flat table type, where you select the dimension you want (event action, event label, etc.) and the "Sessions with Events" metric:

[image]

Alternatively, if it's "Pages with a certain event" that you want, then you can go to the Events > Pages report, and add in an Event type secondary dimension and fiddle around with that.